# Facebook: Graph 'posts' works but FQL 'stream' does not?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

this shouldn't be this difficult.  I assumed it was a permission thing, but then it doesn't make sense when the graph API gives me the information but the FQL doesn't.  :S

so I'm just trying to get the stream from my public page:

http://www.facebook.com/207941570907

So I'm using their tool:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

And I give the Graph API Explorer every single permission and I run this:

https://graph.facebook.com/207941570907/posts

And that works perfectly.. but I want to use FQL instead.  So I figure running the following would be EXACTLY the same, but no data appears?! It WAS working a month ago, but I don't know what they changed..  sigh:

https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT post_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id = 207941570907

Does anyone have a clue what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get, using the graph API explorer, the posts from pages I admin.  I currently have all permissions for the access token I'm using.

Using the Graph API Explorer tool, I'd suggest looking thru the permissions to see which one you are missing.  Or start with all permissions and start taking one by one off until it breaks.

Comment: Well that's not the issue.  with the EXACT SAME permissions set, I can get the data from the GRAPH API but nothing comes up with the FQL.. so one could say that it's ALREADY broken..   ??

Comment: Try with a different app id. Or get all permissions enabled.  It's fairly easy to do with the Graph API Explorer tool.

Comment: Well I DO have all the permissions set.. but I just tried another page of mine.. and it works the opposite!

So the page: https://www.facebook.com/20448754149

I try: https://graph.facebook.com/20448754149/posts

And nothing shows up.. yet when I try:

https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT post_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id = 20448754149

it works?!! what is going here?!  :(

Comment: I manage a lot of pages and applications.  I can get the FQL statement to work with any one of them. I'm really at a loss as to how to help.

Comment: So.. using that tool.. you get the same information when you use BOTH the graph API  AND the FQL the way I did it?

Comment: FQL stream data is NOT the same as `{pageid}/feed` data NOR is either the same as `{pageid}/posts`

Comment: oh.. well that helps a lot..  so then.. do you know the difference between feed / posts / stream ?

Comment: posts: The Page's own posts., feed: The Page's wall., stream: any/all stream items